# Sharepoint 2019 PDF inegration

Tags: 2019, pdf

I have just updated Sharepoint from 2013 to 2019 and all is well except for PDF integration.  In Sharepoint 2013, users can open PDF files directly from SharePoint in Acrobat reader and check it out and comment the file.  When they save it, it saves it back to SharePoint.

In 2019, when I force the system to open the PDF in Acrobat, it opens a local copy so the user needs to upload the file back to Sharepoint.

I've tried multiple solutions from various sites including updating the DocIcon.xml file and running the following command in powershell

Get-SPWOPIBinding –Application "WordPDF" | Remove-SPWOPIBinding
-Confirm:$false

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Two of the best options are:

1. Use OneDrive to open the library
2. Add the location in Adobe and browse to the PDF from Adobe

Unfortunately, outside of that, there's not a lot you can do. Adobe lacks good integration with the modern interface.

Comment: Currently I have turned off the modern interface.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, but only if you use IE with the Adobe ActiveX control.

Comment: So I'm using the classic interface and I am using IE with the active x control enabled and disabled and still can't get it to work.